# is there a way to export the notification center from thingsboard?

Tags: notifications, thingsboard

I am trying to find a way to export my notification center from one thingsboard server to a different one. is it possibale?
if not the whole center maybe there is a way of exporting the templates/rules?
like you export widget and dashboards

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve this:

- Export and Import of the Database tables in the PostgreSQL Database:

[image]

- Using the Administration REST API and the notification controllers:

https://thingsboard.io/docs/pe/reference/rest-api/
[image]

Unfortunately, there is no option yet to export/import via ThingsBoard Web UI (similar to widgets/dashboards). Also notifications are currently not included in the version control feature.